# KVM bridge guest can access Internet but LAN cannot access guest

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I am pulling my hair over this issue: my guest VM registers OK with my router and can access the Internet, but neither the router, host or any LAN computer can even ping the guest

Network: TPLink Router + Host running Ubunter Server 15 with Guest running Windows Server 2012 + Other PCs

I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking) and read in forums that the bridge should solve everything, I made sure that the guest firewall takes pings (and it can ping itself) and yet the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Host `ifconfig`:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:d3:a3:fb
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6ae:52ff:fed3:a3fb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:75546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:67338 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:9073123 (9.0 MB)  TX bytes:13915784 (13.9 MB)

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:d3:a3:fb
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:130010 errors:0 dropped:86 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:37807268 (37.8 MB)  TX bytes:15209842 (15.2 MB)
          Interrupt:16

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:22800 (22.8 KB)  TX bytes:22800 (22.8 KB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:3c:52:2a
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe3c:522a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7664 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:836769 (836.7 KB)  TX bytes:12182959 (12.1 MB)
```

Guest `ipconfig` Ethernet adapter (abridged)

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix : home
Description : Realtek + Fast Ethernet NIC
Physical Address: 52-54-00-xx-xx-xx
DHCP Enabled: Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled: Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address: xxxx
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.3(Preferred)
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server: 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
```

Host `\etc\network\interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eno1
bridge_fd 9
bridge_hello 2
bridge_maxage 12
bridge_stp off
```

Comment: Maybe the guest is set to ignore pings?  When you try to ping it from the host, does `arp` show that it found the guest's IP address?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `arp` -- it shows the guest's IP address: `192.168.1.3              ether   52:54:00:3c:52:2a   C                     br0`

Comment: The guest can ping itself from the command line, and I added a firewall rule to allow pings...

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the firewall issue, I resolved the problem: explanation below

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved!  As pointed out by @psusi this was a (slightly tricky) firewall issue.  The problem was the following: Windows Server firewall distinguishes between three network types: `private, domain, public`

As you might have guessed, the guest firewall rule I had created to allow pings was assigned to `private` by default, whereas the Ethernet adapter was automatically made a `public` network.  Therefore, the firewall was blocking all pings (except those made on the guest itself).

Solutions:

1. Add `public` profile to all relevant firewall rules in the Windows Firewall (in Properties > Advanced tab), OR:
2. Change network type to `private` (see [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/639088/how-do-i-make-a-connection-private-on-windows-server-2012-r2) )

I hope this helps anyone confronted to a similar problem in the future.